# How to indent the code so the answer will be correct?

Tags: javascript, while-loop, indentation

I had this question: What does the following improperly indented while loop display? (hint: rewrite it with proper indentation)

```
var k = 0
while (k < 5)
alert(k)
k++
```

A)  0, 1, 2, 3, 4
B)  1, 2, 3, 4, 5
C)  0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
D)  0, 0 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ... forever

I have found that the answer is D, but I don't know how to rewrite it with proper indentation. Can anyone help me?

Comment: indentation makes no function to the code (at least in javascript)!

Comment: "rewrite it with proper indentation" is a hint because it's a method of helping you see that the answer is D. Indenting the body of the while loop (the `alert`) makes it clear that `k` is never incremented inside the loop, therefore the loop will be infinite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var k = 0
while (k < 5)
alert(k)
k++
```

Without brackets, only one line of the while statement will be considered the body of the while statement.

What you have is an infinite loop because `k++` is never reached because the condition in the while statement is always true. So, the answer is D.

To make the condition reach true, you should add `{` `}` to the `while` statement and include `k++` in the body of the compound statement like this:

```
var k = 0
while (k < 5) {
    alert(k)
    k++
}
```

Comment: No Problem. I hope my answer was clear and understandable, if not I would happy to go further in detail.

Answer (score 1):

Just:

```
var k = 0
while (k < 5)
    alert(k)
k++
```

If you never increment `k` you will never "print" anything other than 0, because `k < 5` is always `true`. You're in an [infinite loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_loop).

If you want your program to *terminate* (end), then you should:

```
var k = 0
while (k < 5){
    alert(k)
    k++
}
```

This way `k` will be "printed" (0,1,2,3,..) until it gets to `k = 5` and then it will stop.

Comment: thats the code those in a , b ,c ,d are the answers

Comment: I posted the "correct" indentation so the answer is D.

Comment: @Andrew that's fine, Idos answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can't fix this only with an indentation change, you need braces.

```
var k = 0
while (k < 5) {
  alert(k)
  k++
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var k = 0
while(k < 5)
{
    alert(k)
    k++
}
```

This should be correct, if you don't put the curly brackets ({,}) only the next line will count as "inside" the loop.